# How to connect postgres data base using javascript

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I'm very new to postgres. I'm trying to connect postgres using javascript but it's not working. How to connect using javascript?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you try (backend or frontend)? Which libraries/frameworks are you using?

Comment: Just use [`pg` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) in your node.js app

Comment: By the way, using vanilla JavaScript in the browser wouldn't be possible to connect to the PostgreSQL server directly. You have to make your queries  in the backend and access them through AJAX from the frontend.

Comment: Javascript is just a language.What runtime are you using? A web browser? node.js? something else?

Comment: var sys = require("sys"); var pg = require("postgres-pure"); var db = new pg.connect("pgsql://test:12345@localhost:5432/template1"); db.query("SELECT * FROM sometable", function (data) { console.log(data); }); db.close();

Comment: I am trying connect using above code but Its not connecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you're trying to do this from within a web browser, which means it just simply ain't gonna work, not no way, not nohow. Most if not all web browsers **do not allow** code within a page to access **any** resource (such as your database) which lies outside the browser; this is simply a security measure to prevent hostile web pages from gaining access to your computer.

If you want to create a web page that accesses a database, you must do so using a **server-side** execution environment such as php or node.js, which can access the database, generate an html page, and then present it to your browser for viewing.